# SQL query to link data in 2 Excel sheets

Tags: sql, excel

I want to link 2 excel tables on different excel sheets. I do this for years without problems. Both excel sheets contain a table with the same reference number so i can link them and job done.

The Excel sheet i got this time from the vendor has little different reference numbers. They all have a character in front of the reference numbers.

```
Sheet 1: Reference number: 12455630098
Sheet 2: Reference number: F12455630098
```

The problem here is that the data is a little different now, so the link can't be made with the code i used previously.

```
SELECT `tab1$`.Référencenumber, `tab1$`.Price, `tab2$`.PARTNO
FROM C:\xxxxxxxxx.file.xlsx
WHERE `tab1$`.Référencenumber = `tab2$`.PARTNO
```

I tried to experiment with the wildcard character to get the job done, but without succes.

This is my SQL code so far.

```
SELECT `tab1$`.Référencenumber, `tab1$`.Price, `tab2$`.PARTNO
FROM C:\xxxxxxxxx.file.xlsx
WHERE `tab1$`.Référencenumber LIKE '%' + `tab2$`.PARTNO
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You have already asked this question once!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run a replace command.

Press `CTRL+H` and when the replace dialog opens search for letter F and replace it with nothing.

Ok, in your previous question you did not made that specific, didn't use SQL in MS producst for a long time, but if I'm right than you there isn't substring function in MS office, instead you have LEFT RIGHT and MID so you should try something like:

```
SELECT `tab1$`.Référencenumber, `tab1$`.Price, `tab2$`.PARTNO
FROM C:\xxxxxxxxx.file.xlsx
WHERE `tab1$`.Référencenumber = MID(`tab2$`.PARTNO,2,LEN(`tab2$`.PARTNO)-1)
```

Not 100% sure about the keywords...

Comment: That is not an option they are updated reference number that are used in a ERP system.

Comment: I tested if the query was succesful and it seems it is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
SELECT `tab1$`.Référencenumber, `tab1$`.Price, `tab2$`.PARTNO
FROM C:\xxxxxxxxx.file.xlsx
WHERE `tab1$`.Référencenumber = substring(`tab2$`.PARTNO,2,11)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my example I gave the reference number 11 digits, but they have variable length.